# Simple Math in C?

Tags: c

instructions:
set amount of money for frozen yogurt. adult will eat a certain ratio to the child. each ounce of yogurt is 0.49. for some reason this isn't working and i can't figure out why. I know which line is causing it trouble, i bolded and italicized it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

# define SALES_TAX 0.065
# define PRICE_PER_OZ 0.49

int main()
{
    float totalcash;
    double ratio;
    double totalbeforetax;
    float totalounces;
    double adultounces;
    double childounces;


    //user input for total cash and scanning
    printf("How many dollars do you have for frozen yogurt?\n");

    //scan in total cash
    scanf("%f", &totalcash);

    //user input for ratio and scanning
    printf("What is the ratio of yogurt that you'll get to your child?\n");

    //scan in ratio
    scanf("%lf", &ratio);

    //solve for values
    totalbeforetax = (totalcash)/(1+SALES_TAX);
    totalounces = totalbeforetax/(PRICE_PER_OZ);
    //adultounces = childounces*ratio;
    ***adultounces = (totalounces-adultounces)*(ratio);***
   // childounces = adultounces/ratio;
    childounces = totalounces-adultounces;



    //output
    printf("You will get %.2lf ounces of yogurt.\n",adultounces);
    printf("Your child will get %.2lf ounces of yougrt\n", childounces);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answers it gives me is adult: 18.68 ounces and the child -6.23 when i put in total dollars is 6.50 and ratio is 1.5. it should give me 7.47 and 4.98

Comment: `adultounces = (totalounces-adultounces)*(ratio);` what is this? you calculating value depending on it's previous [non-initialized] value? It could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the math is simple:

```
childounces = totalounces / (1+ratio);
adultounces = totalounces - childounces;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I was overthinking it!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `adultounces` before using it in your calculation.  You'll need to do a bit of algebra to figure out how to do the calculation from what you have.

hint:

```
adult + child = ratio*child + child = total
```